# Регулярное выражение, которое не хочет отрабатывать PyCharm

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pycharm

Господа. Написал регулярное выражение для фильтрации паспортных данных, типа '5303 407600/31.01.2000/ОВД г. Новотроицка, Оренбургской области, код подразделения 562-007'. Интерпретатор Python 3 глотает с удовольствием выражение, а отладчик PyCharm нет, и идет по исключению (`else`). Почему так происходит?

```
pass_data = '5303 407600/31.01.2000/ОВД г. Новотроицка, Оренбургской области'
if re.match('^\d{4}\s{1}\d{6}\/\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}/.*', pass_data):
    # Некоторые действия, если строка отвечает формату выражения
else:
    # Если не отвечает, то исполняем это.
```

Данное выражение должно проверять наличие Серии и номера паспорта, даты выдачи, и что-то типа кем выдано.

Comment: У меня в PyCharm  нормально работает. Возможно, у вас просто опечатка где-то?

Comment: А так: `r'^\d{4}\s\d{6}/\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}/.*'`?

Comment: Ваш вариант получился почти верен, с маленькой поправочкой:         m = re.match(r"\d{4}\s{1}\d{6}\/\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}/.*", pass_data) Большое спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем выражении, которое в принципе правильное, есть неточности:

- [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) не требует `^` в начале выражения, так как поиск ведётся только в начале текста
- `\s{1}` = `\s` - квантификатор `{1}` не требуется, он подразумевается (`Вася` = `В{1}а{1}с{1}я{1}`)
- `\/` можно в регулярном выражении писать как `/`, так как прямой слеш не является специальным оператором регулярных выражений
- . в регулярном выражении находит любой символ, отличный от символа перевода строки. `\d{2}.\d{4}` найдет `12%1234`.

Предлагаю

```
if re.match('\d{4}\s\d{6}/\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}/.*', pass_data):
```

Это выражение находит совпадение

- только в начале строки
- `\d{4}` - 4 цифры
- `\s` - один пробельный символ
- `\d{6}` - 6 цифр
- `/` - прямой слеш
- `\d{2}` - 2 цифры
- `\.` - символ точки
- `\d{2}\.\d{4}` - 2 цифры, точка, 4 цифры
- `/.*` - слеш и после него 0 и более символов, отличных от символа перевода строки.